# Is there a Windows 8 equivalent of 'Recent Items'/'My Recent Documents'?

Tags: windows-8

I used to use "Recent Items" and "My Recent Documents" in the start menu in previous versions of Windows to quickly open a recently opened document/activity.

Is there an equivalent aggregated list of recent documents in Windows 8, or is it just per application?

If there isn't an equivalent, is there a way I can quickly access a list of recently accessed, opened, and edited documents?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this: Just open the run dialog box by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type in "`recent`".  There you can see your recent activities.

**Note**: "Recent places" can be access under Windows Explorer's under "Favorite".

Also you can create a shortcut of the "`recent`" at your desktop and then pin it to start menu. For this just right click on desktop and seclect `New>Shortcut`. In file location type the path

> C:/users/username/recent

and click the `Next` button, it will prompt the name and now click `Finish`. You will see the shortcut on desktop now and you can pin it to start menu. Also you can define `Hotkey` for this from properties now.

Comment: No idea why this has been accepted as an answer. Typing "recent" into the run dialog results in an error.

Comment: May be something going wrong on your side, I had use that command without any problem. Alas! now I don't have Win8 for your query at the moment, but I'm sure you should have to give a try to `sfc /scannnow` for any error on your system.

Comment: Win8 Pro 64bit en-US here, works fine.

Comment: Error Message: Windows can not find 'recent'

Comment: pretty fresh install (few weeks old), 'windows cannot find recent' when used in run dialog. Also, recent places in explorer is just a list of recently accessed folders, not documents

Comment: @danwellman give a try to `shell:recent' command and see if it helps you. As it works on windows 7 and I don't have Windows 8 now. So can't dig deep for this.

Comment: Thanks, I actually used Gord's suggestion below and it worked well for my situation :)

Comment: @danwellman Hmmm so you mean none of my suggestion didn't worked for you. I made a search on Google and its happen with many users that they got the problem with this command and some users could use it without any problems. Strnage issue.

Comment: Well, I was able to open recent places in Explorer, but it was a collection of folders I'd opened recently, whereas what I wanted was documents opened recently. Your advice was sound, just not what I needed :)

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 8 or 8.1 Update

Comment: "as it works on windows 7 and I don't have Windows 8 now." - question is tagged Windows 8

Comment: @nathanchere that means this command works on Windows 7 so should be on Windows 8, and it was as I used it on Windows 8 enterprise release. Now I don't use Windows 8 because I love Windows 7 more. The answer I provided checked on windows 8 and then answered here, also answer accepted because it worked for the OP.

Comment: When you type something in the "Run" box, you are running it from your `C:\Users\<username>` folder. So just run "." to browse it with file explorer ("." = current folder) and look for a "Recent" or similar entry. You must have enabled the option to see hidden and system folders. Otherwise, run `dir r* /a` in that folder to find it. The "Recent" folder is a hidden and system joint folder pointing to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`. If your Windows is in another language, this joint folder may have a different name, like "Reciente" for Spanish.

Answer (score 15):

Since avirk's solution didn't work for me I searched further and found a similar solution in *[Is there a Windows 8 "Recent Items" Jump List?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-hardware/is-there-a-windows-8-recent-items-jump-list/27c7eb94-f3be-4046-8298-dc477c868dcf)* .

It says you can access the **recent files** via

```
C:\Users\[YourName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
```

I had to **navigate manually** to the location, but then I could drag the folder to the "Favorites" icon.

So I finally got a working solution now.

Comment: This should be the right answer (for Win 8).

Comment: In Windows 8 I have a "Recent" joint folder in C:\Users\<username>, which points to that AppData folder. Have you browsed that folder in your PC to see if it's really not there? You should see it if you run this from a console: `C:\Users\yourusername>dir r* /a`.

Answer (score 13):

You can pin your applications (such as [Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) or [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)) to the taskbar. Once you do that, you'll have your recent item list for that application when you right click the icon.

Answer (score 4):

Launch File Explorer. There is a *Recent Places* link under *Favourites*. This includes all sorts of things that are not documents.

You could pin the associated application to the Taskbar. You then right-click and see a jumplist of recent documents, but this is application specific. All we want is an easily exposed method to see a menu list of recent documents that doesn't require you to launch a shortcut to a folder of other shortcuts. Windows 7 had this, Windows 8 does not.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> "recent" thing doesn't seem to work, or at least work reliably for everyone. I've found what I think is a better solution and it'll work for everyone.

Open a Command Prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd` and hit enter).

By default this should start in your user directory, for example `C:\Users\UserName`. If you're not already there, change to that directory. Run the following command:

```
mklink /J "Recent Items" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
```

This will create a link to your recent items in your home directory that is also navigable via the folder view on the left side of Explorer, which a normal shortcut is not.

Comment: This is a nice solution. To make it even better and quicker to access your recent items, you can create a Windows Taskbar toolbar item out of this since it acts like a folder. Just right-click the taskbar -> Toolbars -> New toolbar... and select the new reference created by the cmd above. Now you can access the items directly from the taskbar!

Answer (score -1):

1. Just open the run dialog box by pressing Win + R and type in "recent". There you can see your recent activities in the Explorer window.
2. In this Explorer window, right-click the icon for the “recent” path and choose Copy address.
3. Now, go to the Desktop and right-click and choose Paste shortcut.  A shortcut icon pointing to “recent” will be created.  You can now right-click this icon and choose Pin to start.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Windows Explorer, My Computer or press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> key.
2. Navigate to "C:\USERS\"USERNAME"\". "USERNAME" is the name you logged onto Windows with.
3. "The recent folder should be in the list shown.
4. Right-click on the folder and select pin to start.

The recent folder will now be on the start screen. When you open it you see all  your recent files and folders.  Right-click on any file for the context menu.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the file search tile - then type in the partial file name.

Comment: The point of the recent items is surely that you don't remember the file name