# Where are the "Recent-Items" and "Most Frequently Used Apps" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Doesn't Windows 8 keep track of the apps that I'm using like the earlier versions of Windows which automatically listed the most frequently used software's in the Start menu?

I can't seem to find a "Recent Documents" feature as well. Is it not available in Windows 8 or am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Is there a windows 8 equivalent of 'Recent Items'/'My Recent Documents'?](http://superuser.com/q/492223/117590) for recent documents. That question does not address apps, however. I think you are expected to manually arrange the apps you use more often as tiles on the the start screen, much like the Android home screen.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the solution mentioned there [**WIN + R**] does seem to work, but sadly it seems its not as user friendly as in previous Windows versions.

Comment: Regarding apps. Is there any way to designate a portion on the start screen where the most frequently used apps automatically show up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature was removed, because there is no longer a start menu.

Your options are:

- An application's recent documents/files jump list is still available, but only if pinned to the taskbar (since there is no start menu anymore)
- You can setup a shortcut to "Recent" in your user folder, which lists everything you have accessed.
- Restore the start menu, using a 3rd party application, which includes the recent documents, just like in Windows 7. Start menu replacements include:

  - [ViStart](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/) (free!)
  - [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) (free!)
  - [Pokki](https://www.pokki.com/) (free!)
  - [StartMenu7](http://www.startmenu7.com/index.html) (free with pro version for sale)
  - [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/index.asp) ($5)

Sources:

- [Where did my Recent Items go in Windows 8?](http://bennettadelson.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/where-did-my-recent-items-go-in-windows-8/) - Bennett Adelson Technical Blog
- [How to get the classic Start menu back in Windows 8 RTM](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-33642_7-57496506-292/how-to-get-the-classic-start-menu-back-in-windows-8-rtm/) - CNET
- [How to restore the classic Start menu with Pokki for Windows 8](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-33642_7-57534343-292/how-to-restore-the-classic-start-menu-with-pokki-for-windows-8/) - CNET

Answer (score 1):

For "mostly used" apps I found this feature that Windows 8 have, nothing else.[image]