# Is there a way to access recent files in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a windows 8 equivalent of ‘Recent Items’/‘My Recent Documents’?](https://superuser.com/questions/492223/is-there-a-windows-8-equivalent-of-recent-items-my-recent-documents)

Is there a way to access recent files in Windows 8? It's one of the most-used/needed features for me.

Comment: Hi Clay! Please keep questions reasonably scoped and only post one question at a time. If they're really not related (other than having to do with Windows Search), post them separately please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Recent Items folder still exists.
Go to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows"
Of course, no nice menu exists as there was with windows 7, but you can always pin this to Start and almost get the same effect.

Comment: Excellent - that works like the proverbial gangbusters; I gave it a shortcut key of R.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open explorer and browse to `C:\Users\<your username>`
2. Right-click on “Recent” and select “Pin to Start” image
3. You can then find it in the start menu and rename it to something you find faster to type in Search or leave it as is.

[Source](http://bennettadelson.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/where-did-my-recent-items-go-in-windows-8/)

Comment: Do you mean ".recently-used.xbel"?

Answer (score 1):

you can still access them from the jumplist of an application after lunching the app in the desktop.
[This](http://bennettadelson.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/where-did-my-recent-items-go-in-windows-8/) article has more details on it