# How to turn off 'Recent Items'/'My Recent Documents' in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

For privacy concerns, is there a way to turn off all "recent" storage in Windows 8? Note that this is the inverse of this question:

[Is there a Windows 8 equivalent of 'Recent Items'/'My Recent Documents'?](https://superuser.com/questions/492223/is-there-a-windows-8-equivalent-of-recent-items-my-recent-documents)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable recently access files disable it through the "Taskbar properties"

1. Go to search and lookup "taskbar". (Located in Settings)
2. Click on "Taskbar"
3. Uncheck "Store and display recently opened items in Jump Lists.

If you'd like to remove "Recent Places" you can simply right click it and remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Does [this](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-7-8-disable-recent-items-in-jump-list/) help?

> First, right click the Start Menu Orb / Button and click Properties.
>
> Click Start Menu Tab (Or Jump Lists Tab for Windows 8) and uncheck the box Store and display recently opened items in the Start Menu and the taskbar. Click OK when done.

There is also the `store recent documents and applications shortcuts` Option in `Taskbar Properties –> Jump Lists` as explained [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-8-clear-documents-shortcuts-jump-list-items-at-log-off/) (might be the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file explorer. from Task bar icon or Press WINDOWS KEY+E keys. File explorer will appear on screen.
Now click on FILE tab and Change Folder And Search Options from the menu.
New folder options tab will appear. Look under General Tab in Privacy section, Now you need to unchecked Show Recently Used Files In Quick Access.
Click On Apply and then OK to save the settings. Now you will not see the recent files in quick access menu.

For more [INFO](https://www.tekhgizmo.com/remove-recent-files-from-quick-access-in-windows-10/)